# I am getting an Servlet /SpringCRUD threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, maven, classnotfoundexception, loader

I am aware that this is a duplicate question but I could not find my solution in any of the previous answers. I have tried all the solutions from the answers:

1. I have added the below in my pom.xml

   org.springframework
       spring-context
       3.1.0.RELEASE


      org.springframework
      spring-webmvc
      3.1.0.RELEASE
2. Also I have added the maven dependencies in Deployment Assembly

[image]

I have redeployed the code after these changes, still I am getting the error:

[image]

Is there any other solution for this?

Adding the screenshots of pom.xml

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide a screen with libraries (maven dependencies) ?

Comment: I have added the screenshots for pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Well,this error occurs when the class you mentioned cannot be found in the classpath, add your pom.xml file so we can diagnose it.

try adding this to your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This I already had in my pom.xml. Still it is not working, I have added the screenshots